# Product as linear combination of squared linear combinations

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, recreational-mathematics

**Edit:**

This question is an old version and could be closed. More details can be found in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4349239/737314).

**Motivation**

A product of two factors can also be written as linear combination of squared linear combinations

$$x_1x_2=\frac{1}{4}(x_1+x_2)^2-\frac{1}{4}(x_1-x_2)^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n_2} a_i \left(\sum_{j=1}^{2}b_{i,j}x_j\right)^2$$
with $n_2=2,a_1=\frac{1}{4},a_2=-\frac{1}{4},b_{1,1}=1,b_{1,2}=1,b_{2,1}=1,b_{2,2}=-1$.

Similarly, for 3 factors it was found by user *Essaidi*
$$x_1x_2x_3=\frac{1}{24}(x_1+x_2+x_3)^3−\frac{1}{24}(−x_1+x_2+x_3)^3−\frac{1}{24}(x_1−x_2+x_3)^3−\frac{1}{24}(x_1+x_2−x_3)^3$$

However this simple pattern does not continue.

**Question**

Which real coefficients $a_i,b_{i,j}$ fulfill the product of four factors?
$$x_1x_2x_3x_4=\sum_{i=1}^{n_4} a_i\left( \sum_{j=1}^{4}b_{i,j}x_j \right)^4$$

**General Question**

Which real coefficients $a_i,b_{i,j}$ fulfill the product of $k$ factors with $k\in \mathbb{N}^+$ ?

$$\prod_{j=1}^k x_j=\sum_{i=1}^{n_k} a_i\left( \sum_{j=1}^{k}b_{i,j}x_j \right)^k$$

*Note:*

The smallest possible $n_k$ is of interest.
It is allowed for some $b_{i,j}=0$.

Comment: It is a bad habit to alert the question after others have posted an answer. Please consider asking another question for the case $k\ge 4$ and restore the post to the original question.

Comment: I have reverted this question to a point where the question and answer now align. If you have a different question to ask, I suggest writing a different answer.

Comment: The title and the text of the question do not fit. The title and first sentence speak about squares, but in the rest of the text we find cubics and higher powers. I will place a new question but fear that this might be not possible due to similarity.

Comment: Is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4349239/12952) the new version?

Comment: Yes this is the new version

Answer (score 3):

There aren't such coefficients when $k \geq 3$. In fact consider the case :
$$x_1 = x_2 = \cdots = x_k = x$$
We will have :
$$x^k = \sum_{i = 1}^{n_k} a_i \left(\sum_{j = 1}^k b_{i, j}\right)^2 x^2$$
Contradiction, because we have two polynomials with different degrees.
It only works when $k = 2$.

Comment: Suppose the formula works and apply it to $\lambda x_1, \ldots, \lambda x_k$.
You will have $\lambda^k$ in the LHS and only $\lambda^2$ in the RHS.
Necessarily k must be 2

Comment: In case $k = 3$ we have :
$$x y z = \dfrac{1}{24} \left((x + y + z)^3 - (-x + y + z)^3 - (x - y + z)^3 - (x + y - z)^3\right)$$