# How to write sums of combinations of signed sums?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, combinations

I am looking for a short way to write sums of combinations of $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ for a practical [application](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4353201/737314). It can be  easier explained using an example:

For $n=3$ there are $2^3=8$ combinations to sum $x_1,x_2,x_3$ using all signed combinations: $$C_3=-f\left(-x_1-x_2-x_3\right)+f\left(x_1-x_2-x_3\right)+f\left(-x_1+x_2-x_3\right)-f\left(x_1+x_2-x_3\right)+f\left(-x_1-x_2+x_3\right)-f\left(x_1-x_2+x_3\right)-f\left(-x_1+x_2+x_3\right)+f\left(x_1+x_2+x_3\right)$$
Every combination are summed arguments of a function $f$ and has a different sign sequence.  The signs of $f$ are negative/positive if the number of negative signs in the arguments are odd/even.

For $n=4$ there are already $2^4=16$ combinations and it is quite ineffective to write them all down:
$$C_4=f\left(-x_1-x_2-x_3-x_4\right)-f\left(x_1-x_2-x_3-x_4\right)-f\left(-x_1+x_2-x_3-x_4\right)+f\left(x_1+x_2-x_3-x_4\right)-f\left(-x_1-x_2+x_3-x_4\right)+f\left(x_1-x_2+x_3-x_4\right)+f\left(-x_1+x_2+x_3-x_4\right)-f\left(x_1+x_2+x_3-x_4\right)-f\left(-x_1-x_2-x_3+x_4\right)+f\left(x_1-x_2-x_3+x_4\right)+f\left(-x_1+x_2-x_3+x_4\right)-f\left(x_1+x_2-x_3+x_4\right)+f\left(-x_1-x_2+x_3+x_4\right)-f\left(x_1-x_2+x_3+x_4\right)-f\left(-x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4\right)+f\left(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4\right)$$

It is clear that for higher $n$ a short notation is needed. I do not look for a program code.

Comment: After a closer look, it seems that I don't understand your definition of $C_n$. I thought the rule was that if there are an odd number of minus signs in the bracket, then the sign before it is also minus. But this doesn't match your expressions. Nevertheless both $C_3$ and $C_4$ are zero, so maybe you should still give an example of $n$ such that $C_n$ is nonzero.

Comment: @WhatsUp An application was added in the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can write $C_n$, for every non-negative integer $n$, as $$C_n = \sum_{(s_1, s_2, \dots, s_n) \in \{-1, 1\}^n}s_1s_2\cdots s_n \cdot f\Big(s_1x_1 + s_2x_2 + \dots + s_nx_n\Big),$$
where $\{-1, 1\}^n := \Big\{(s_1, s_2, \dots, s_n) \mid s_i \in \{-1, 1\} \text{ for all positive integers } i \leq n\Big\}$.

The idea is to just use the "variables" $s_i$ to act as the signs.

For example, $\{-1, 1\}^3$ is defined to be
$$\{(\color{red}{-1}, \color{red}{-1}, \color{red}{-1}), (\color{red}{-1}, \color{red}{-1}, \color{green}{+1}), (\color{red}{-1}, \color{green}{+1}, \color{red}{-1}), (\color{red}{-1}, \color{green}{+1}, \color{green}{+1}), (\color{green}{+1}, \color{red}{-1}, \color{red}{-1}), (\color{green}{+1}, \color{red}{-1}, \color{green}{+1}), (\color{green}{+1}, \color{green}{+1}, \color{red}{-1}), (\color{green}{+1}, \color{green}{+1}, \color{green}{+1})\},$$
so we have
\begin{align*}
C_3 = & \: (\color{red}{-1})(\color{red}{-1})(\color{red}{-1})  \cdot f\Big((\color{red}{-1})x_1 + (\color{red}{-1})x_2 + (\color{red}{-1})x_3\Big) \:+ \\
& \: (\color{red}{-1})(\color{red}{-1})(\color{green}{+1})  \cdot f\Big((\color{red}{-1})x_1 + (\color{red}{-1})x_2 + (\color{green}{+1})x_3\Big) \:+ \\
& \: (\color{red}{-1})(\color{green}{+1})(\color{red}{-1})  \cdot f\Big((\color{red}{-1})x_1 + (\color{green}{+1})x_2 + (\color{red}{-1})x_3\Big) \:+ \\
& \: (\color{red}{-1})(\color{green}{+1})(\color{green}{+1})  \cdot f\Big((\color{red}{-1})x_1 + (\color{green}{+1})x_2 + (\color{green}{+1})x_3\Big) \:+ \\
& \: (\color{green}{+1})(\color{red}{-1})(\color{red}{-1})  \cdot f\Big((\color{green}{+1})x_1 + (\color{red}{-1})x_2 + (\color{red}{-1})x_3\Big) \:+ \\
& \: (\color{green}{+1})(\color{red}{-1})(\color{green}{+1})  \cdot f\Big((\color{green}{+1})x_1 + (\color{red}{-1})x_2 + (\color{green}{+1})x_3\Big) \:+ \\
& \: (\color{green}{+1})(\color{green}{+1})(\color{red}{-1})  \cdot f\Big((\color{green}{+1})x_1 + (\color{green}{+1})x_2 + (\color{red}{-1})x_3\Big) \:+ \\
& \: (\color{green}{+1})(\color{green}{+1})(\color{green}{+1})  \cdot f\Big((\color{green}{+1})x_1 + (\color{green}{+1})x_2 + (\color{green}{+1})x_3\Big).
\end{align*}

Comment: @granularbastard You're referring to the definition of $\{-1, 1\}^n$? You can think of it as the set of all tuples of length $n$ whose elements are either $-1$ or $1$. So, for example, the set $\{-1, 1\}^3$ is defined to be $$\{(-1, -1, -1), (-1, -1, 1), (-1, 1, -1), (-1, 1, 1), (1, -1, -1), (1, -1, 1), (1, 1, -1), (1, 1, 1)\}.$$

Comment: is this a common definition or just your idea?

Comment: @granularbastard I don't know if it's common or not, but I've seen this notation in some combinatorics papers such as [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.00847.pdf) and [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316592900608) to denote the vertex set of the [hypercube graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube_graph). You can also think of them as [$n$-ary Cartesian power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#n-ary_Cartesian_power).

Answer (score 2):

> Using $[n]:=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ we can write $C_n, n\geq 1$ as
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{C_n=\sum_{S\subseteq [n]}(-1)^{\left|[n]\setminus S\right|}f\left(\sum_{j\in S}x_j-\sum_{j\in[n]\setminus S}x_j\right)}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

**Example: $n=3$:** Following (1) we can write $C_3$ as
\begin{align*}
C_3&=(-1)^{\left|[3]\setminus[3]\right|}f(x_1+x_2+x_3)\\
&\qquad+(-1)^{\left|[3]\setminus\{1,2\}\right|}f(x_1+x_2-x_3)
+(-1)^{\left|[3]\setminus\{1,3\}\right|}f(x_1+x_3-x_2)\\
&\qquad+(-1)^{\left|[3]\setminus\{2,3\}\right|}f(x_2+x_3-x_1)\\
&\qquad+(-1)^{\left|[3]\setminus\{1\}\right|}f(x_1-x_2-x_3)
+(-1)^{\left|[3]\setminus\{2\}\right|}f(x_2-x_1-x_3)\\
&\qquad+(-1)^{\left|[3]\setminus\{3\}\right|}f(x_3-x_1-x_2)\\
&\qquad+(-1)^{\left|[3]\setminus\emptyset\right|}f(-x_1-x_2-x_3)
\end{align*}
in accordance with OP's stated $C_3$.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @VTand's answer I think you can also write

$$C_n = \sum_{t_1, t_2, \dots, t_n = 0}^1  \epsilon^{t_1}\epsilon^{t_2}\dots \epsilon^{t_n} ~f\Big(\epsilon^{t_1}x_1 + \epsilon^{t_1} x_2 + \dots + \epsilon^{t_1} x_n\Big), $$ where $\epsilon = -1$. In relation to @VTand's example, we have:

\begin{align*}
C_3 = & \: (\color{red}{-1})^{1}(\color{red}{-1})^{1}(\color{red}{-1})^{\color{blue}{1}}  \cdot f\Big((\color{red}{-1})^{\color{blue}{1}}x_1 + (\color{red}{-1})^{\color{blue}{1}}x_2 + (\color{red}{-1})^{\color{blue}{1}}x_3\Big) \:+ \\
& \: (\color{red}{-1})^{\color{blue}{1}}(\color{red}{-1})^{\color{blue}{1}}(\color{green}{-1})^{\color{blue}{0}}  \cdot f\Big((\color{red}{-1})^{\color{blue}{1}}x_1 + (\color{red}{-1})^{\color{blue}{1}}x_2 + (\color{green}{-1})^{\color{blue}{0}}x_3\Big) \:+ \\
& \: (\color{red}{-1})^{\color{blue}{1}}(\color{green}{-1})^{\color{blue}{0}}(\color{red}{-1})^{\color{blue}{1}}  \cdot f\Big((\color{red}{-1})^{\color{blue}{1}}x_1 + (\color{green}{-1})^{\color{blue}{0}}x_2 + (\color{red}{-1})^{\color{blue}{1}}x_3\Big) \:+ \\
& \: (\color{red}{-1})^{\color{blue}{1}}(\color{green}{-1})^{\color{blue}{0}}(\color{green}{-1})^{\color{blue}{0}}  \cdot f\Big((\color{red}{-1})^{\color{blue}{1}}x_1 + (\color{green}{-1})^{\color{blue}{0}}x_2 + (\color{green}{-1})^{\color{blue}{0}}x_3\Big) \:+ \\
& \: (\color{green}{-1})^{\color{blue}{0}}(\color{red}{-1}^{\color{blue}{1}})(\color{red}{-1})^{\color{blue}{1}}  \cdot f\Big((\color{green}{-1})^{\color{blue}{0}}x_1 + (\color{red}{-1})^{\color{blue}{1}}x_2 + (\color{red}{-1})^{\color{blue}{1}}x_3\Big) \:+ \\
& \: (\color{green}{-1})^{\color{blue}{0}}(\color{red}{-1})^{\color{blue}{1}}(\color{green}{-1})^{\color{blue}{0}}  \cdot f\Big((\color{green}{-1})^{\color{blue}{0}}x_1 + (\color{red}{-1})^{\color{blue}{1}}x_2 + (\color{green}{-1})^{\color{blue}{0}}x_3\Big) \:+ \\
& \: (\color{green}{-1})^{\color{blue}{0}}(\color{green}{-1})^{\color{blue}{0}}(\color{red}{-1})^{\color{blue}{1}}  \cdot f\Big((\color{green}{-1})^{\color{blue}{0}}x_1 + (\color{green}{-1})^{\color{blue}{0}}x_2 + (\color{red}{-1})^{\color{blue}{1}}x_3\Big) \:+ \\
& \: (\color{green}{-1})^{\color{blue}{0}}(\color{green}{-1})^{\color{blue}{0}}(\color{green}{-1})^{\color{blue}{0}}  \cdot f\Big((\color{green}{-1})^{\color{blue}{0}}x_1 + (\color{green}{-1})^{\color{blue}{0}}x_2 + (\color{green}{-1})^{\color{blue}{0}}x_3\Big).
\end{align*}